# Spring Boot: hot swapping does not work

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, jetty

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.2 with gradle plugin. In my multipart project hot swapping/reload for HTML/JS/CSS files does not work.

```
/resources
  |-wro.groovy
  |-application.yml
  |-/templates/(all *.html files and index.html)
  |-/static/
      |-/js/
      |-/css/
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
 port: 8080

spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
    prefix: classpath:/templates/
    suffix: .html
    enabled: true
    encoding: UTF-8
    mode: HTML5
```

In te projet also used: wro4j, thymeleaf, AngularJS

Part of **gradle.build**

```
buildscript {
    ext { springBootVersion = '1.3.2.RELEASE' }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://ourartifactoryUrl/plugins-release"
            credentials {
                // artifactory log and pass
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: springBootVersion
        classpath group: 'io.spring.gradle', name: 'dependency-management-plugin', version: '0.5.2.RELEASE'
        classpath group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '3.1.+'
        classpath 'org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-maven'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-eclipse'


...


dependencies {
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

Project executed with: `gradle :web-admin:bootRun`

**Update/Answer:**

After some surfing in internet and reading spring-boot docs I found one trick. 
Problem in using [`devtools` together with `spring-boot-gradle-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-running-applications) as a result I simply need to add to my **gradle.build** file few lines:

```
    // Used by 'Spring Boot Gradle Plugin' in combination with 'Devtools' makes HTML/JS/CSS reloadable.
    bootRun {
        addResources = true
    }
```

Comment: This is different enough from my setup (running in Eclipse with Maven) that I'm not sure about the details, but check whether your application is serving the files out of a packaged jar instead of out of the development classpath.

Comment: Check updates. Found one trick.

Comment: If this fixed the problem for you, then post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Posted, but I can not accept it.

Comment: There's a minimum time; it'll be available in about a day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some surfing in internet and reading spring-boot docs I found one trick. Problem in using devtools together with spring-boot-gradle-plugin as a result I simply need to add to my gradle.build file few lines:

```
// Used by 'Spring Boot Gradle Plugin' in combination with 'Devtools' makes HTML/JS/CSS reloadable.
bootRun {
    addResources = true
}
```

Comment: In my case it was `sourceResources sourceSets.main` like mentioned in [Gradle Plugin - 6.2 Reloading Resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/) that helped.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and i resolved it by setting `spring.thymeleaf.cache` in the application properties to `false`

> How to Fix

Add `spring.thymeleaf.cache=false` in your `application.properties` file