# IntelliJ IDEA auto recompile changed classes (on lost focus)

Tags: spring, grails

I am aware, that it's IntelliJ IDEA developer's decision, to do not add this feature, as it is not atomic and may create problems.

I also know, that IntelliJ IDEA allows to configure deployment on lost focus, however at same time, Spring Boot application is not recognized as application server, and thus cannot really "deploy" anything.

The thing is, when using Grails, it works great!
On every focus lost, IntelliJ IDEA recompiles required classes.

My question is: how to configure IntelliJ IDEA, so that I can auto recompile changed class on focus lost in Spring Boot project, like it works on Grails?

As Grails uses same technology (Spring Boot/Loaded), I am sure it is possible, I just do not know how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot + Spring-Loaded (IntelliJ, Gradle)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371111/spring-boot-spring-loaded-intellij-gradle)

Comment: See these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371111/spring-boot-spring-loaded-intellij-gradle                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399586/spring-boot-developer-machine                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919315/spring-boot-hot-deployment-for-templates-and-resources-under-intellij